# Is there a broader class of total functions than $PR$?

Tags: computability, computation-models, primitive-recursion

In [total functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_functional_programming) programs are restricted to total computable functions. A well-known class of total functions are the primitive recursive functions ($PR$). However the Ackermann function and others aren't part of $PR$. Is there a well-defined class of total functions which is broader than $PR$?

Bonus question:
I heard lately about Walther and substructural recursion, but I can't find any information whether they are just another definition of $PR$ or different classes of total functions. Could you please clarify? Also a little example on how the definition differ from $PR$ would be great.

Comment: What about R itself? Granted, there can be no programming language [capturing exactly R](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/266/why-are-the-total-functions-not-enumerable), but that's not what you are asking. Or is it? In that case, see this [related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11936/98).

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a definition of total recursive functions which can capture more total functions than PR. Since R can not be captured, there must be various attempts to define larger subsets of R which can be captured.

Comment: Did you check the question I linked?

Comment: The questions mentions Calculus of Construction (CoC, used by Coq), System F and System T. So, is CoC the largest set of well-defined total functions?

Comment: I don't know. Seems to me that would be a whole different question which you should post separately. (Should we close this one as a duplicate?)

Comment: Yes, I'm fine with closing the question as duplicate. Although I hoped to get a clarification about the Walther/Substructural recursion.

Comment: Just post that as another question, I guess!