# Does every r.e. set containing the set of total recursive functions contain all partial recursive functions?

Tags: computability

Any r.e. subset of $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ which contains the set $$\mathrm{Tot}=\{i\mid i\ \mbox{is an index of a total function } f\}$$ must, by a standard argument (of Post?) contain *some* partial recursive function indices.

Given a partial function index (and every total function), it's pretty easy to construct many others, e.g. an index for the function which returns $0$ on prime inputs and is undefined otherwise.

But must $A$ contain *all* partial functions? This seems like a simple question, but I can't find an argument one way or the other.

Edit: I'm equally (more, actually) interested in the case where $A$ is *recursive*, e.g., represents the programs from some programing language.

Comment: It can contain all but finitely many partial functions, so that's one example.

Comment: When does a set contain a function? How are you encoding functions?

Comment: It is very likely that there are some *recursive* sets which do not contain all partial recursive functions, for example an appropriate cofinite set. But the answer depends on the definitions of the terms that you use.

Comment: "by a standard argument" -- because [R is not recursively enumerable](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/266/98). That tells you something else: $A \setminus \mathrm{Tot}$ can't be decidable, for instance. In fact, it can't be co-r.e. either.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I'm fixing some standard Gödel encoding $\phi$ of partial recursive functions. A function $f$ is in a set if there is some $i$ such that $\phi_i=f$ and $i$ is in the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A = \{i\ |\ \phi_i(0) \downarrow \}$. It is obviously r.e., and includes $\mathrm{Tot}$.

Yet, it does not contain any index of, say, the always-undefined function $u$. Nor indices for any recursive partial function which is undefined at $0$.

The Kleene set also works: $K = \{i\ |\ \phi_i(i) \downarrow \} \supset \mathrm{Tot}$, yet it does not contain any index for $u$. (And it is r.e.)

Comment: This answers the question as posed, and I'll very likely accept it (I'm going to wait a tiny bit for more potential answers). Unfortunately, it doesn't quite answer my "actual" question which was more along the lines of: "Are there any programing languages which contain all total functions but are not Turing Complete?". Obviously you aren't expected to answer a question I did not actually ask.

Comment: @cody Unfortunately my crystal ball was out of service :-P Still, what about a programming language whose syntax is $(n,p)$ and whose semantics is: if the input is $0$ return $n$, otherwise run the (say, Java) program $p$ on the predecessor of the input. In this language, programs can never diverge at $0$. This is more-or-less a PL related to set $A$ above.

Comment: @cody (By the way, feel free to wait a couple of days, I'm also curious about more elegant solutions)

Comment: @cody See e.g. [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19577/98).

Comment: @Raphael I'm pretty aware of total programing languages, my question is slightly different: can we get *all* total functions *without* being Turing complete (i.e. having *all* partial functions)? My intuition says no.

Comment: @chi in your example, it is very easy to compute an arbitrary partial function given an oracle to $A$: just find the index $i$ such that $\phi_i(n+1)=f(n)$ and return the answer to $\phi(n+1)$ given input $n$. I'm wondering if there are $A$s without this property.