# Why does my answer sheet say the set of computable functions is uncountable?

Tags: computability, enumeration

I'm trying to understand why I can't find room for the set of computable functions in the hotel of the Hilbert's Hotel Paradox.

I was thinking that, because Gödel numbering, I could consider the set of computable functions as numerable (and with cardinality equal to $\mathrm{card}(\mathbb N)$). However, I have an  answer sheet that says otherwise, and makes a proof of that I'm pretty sure that is wrong. At least I don't trust it:

> Suppose that the computable functions set is enumerable, and $f_n$ is a function of the set. Consider $g(n)=f_n(n)+1$, its not in the set, therefore contradiction. Because that proof then the computable functions aren't countable, so they can't fit in the Hilbert Hotel.

Comment: Is $g$ computable?  If you want to show that there is a countable number of computable functions, you simply show that there is a countable number of Turing machines;  Each Turing machine can be described by a finite string.  The set of finite strings is countable.  Are you mixing enumerable and countable?

Comment: The answer sheet you quote seems to be confusing two similar-looking words. "Enumerable" means semi-recursive (i.e., there is a Turing machine that lists all the elements of the set); "DEnumerable" means countable (i.e., has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$. The answer sheet proves that the set of computable functions isn't enumerable but that doesn't mean it's not denumerable.

Comment: Please cite the original problem; this may well be a misunderstanding. Every set of computable functions is countable (because the set of *all* is) but not all are recursively enumerable, e.g. the [set of total functions](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/266/why-are-the-total-functions-not-enumerable?rq=1). (Well, given the phrasing you cite, the author of the answer sheet may just not know their stuff.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are countably many computable functions. If $f_n$ is a complete list of all (total) computable functions, then the function $g(n) = f_n(n)+1$ cannot be any of the functions on the list, and so is not computable. This is one way to construct an uncomputable function.

Comment: So, in the Hotel context: they have room for the "computable functions set", but not for the "all functions set", because the last includes non computable functions, that are not countable?

Comment: Right. There are many more functions than computable functions.

Comment: Ehm, sorry for the downvote ... Don't know how that happened.  Just read the answer now, and saw I had a blue down-arrow on this answer.  It says I downvoted it more than four hours ago and that the vote is locked unless the post is edited ... I have seriously no idea how that happened!