# What is the limit for Turing machines with 2 states and 3 symbols that halt?

Tags: formal-languages, computability, turing-machines

I read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram%27s_2-state_3-symbol_Turing_machine) that a proof has been offered that a Turing Machine **with 2 states and 3 symbols** can be universal (in that it is capable of arbitrary finite computations). Even if this proof is accepted, it is based on a Turing machine that doesn't halt.

**If we consider only computations that *do* halt** (that end on an additional accepting state), the set of initial configurations that produce such computations could be considered a formal language. In that case, what would be the limitation to the class of languages that could be defined by those machines (with 2 states and 3 symbols)? Could they be specified using regular expressions?

Any help is appreciated.

---

The following TM halts and accepts iff the initial configuration is $(d_{1}01^*[1]d_{2} + d_{3}[0]d_{4})$, where $d_{i} \in \Sigma^\infty$, and $[x]$ (with $x \in \Sigma$) denotes the position of the tape head.

[image]

Comment: There can be no such (i.e. computable) characterisation of the set of always terminating Turing machines. That would solve the Halting problem. See also [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/266/why-are-the-total-functions-not-enumerable). (Duplicate?) In particular, it's definitely not the same set as those for REG since REG $\subsetneq$ CSL $\subsetneq$ R.

Comment: You mean it can only be found out if we took them one by one, right?

Comment: Since I don't understand what you mean by that, I don't think that I mean that.

Comment: A characterization of the kinds of languages that can be defined by machines from this finite (and approachable) set. That's what I mean.

Comment: What do you mean by 'approachable'? Can you enumerate them? Can you find out, given a machine, whether it is one?

Comment: I've already narrowed the set of different MTs with 2 states and 3 symbols to less than $10^6$ (using symmetries, etc.). All machines I have sampled so far define languages that are regular. Given a particular machine, I can obviously study it as a particular problem, and find out if I can use, for instance, a regular expression to define the language for which it halts and accepts. What I want to know is if there is a general characterization for the whole set, i.e., if this problem has already been studied and solved.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what it means to "consider only computations that do halt", especially since (in general) we can't necessarily predict which computations will halt -- there's no general algorithm to do it.  Are you asking about the set of languages accepted by such a TM?  But the standard definition of the language accepted by a TM already only "considers" computations that eventually halt, so I'm not sure why you add this redundant restriction.  Maybe your question is: If $M$ is a TM with 2 states and 3 symbols, is $L(M)$ guaranteed to be regular?

Comment: Yes, $L(M)$ being defined as the set of initial configurations for which the machine stops. I've adapted the notation for reg. expressions to include a symbol for cells that won't be reached, so I'm always talking about the entire tape, not particular words. Hope this makes things clearer. I'll edit the question, if necessary.